# How do I properly add unique design elements to a dropdown box and properly port it to wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

First time posting here.  I wanted to know how do I properly add unique design elements to a drop-down box?  If you look at the image example attached.  Image A has a little triangle at the top of the drop-down box that points to the link.This is something I programmed in. When I port the navigation to WordPress, that unique element (the triangle) disappears (Image B). I am using Bootstrap Navwalker to make the menu in Wordpress.

[image]

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
<div class="gold-triangle"></div>
  <a class="dropdown-item active" href="admissions.html">Admission 
 Process</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item pt-2" href="tour.html">Visit Our School</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item pt-2" href="tuition.html">Tuition &amp; 
     Fees</a>
</div>
```

CSS Code for Triangle

```
    .navbar-custom .dropdown-menu .gold-triangle {
      width: 0em; height: 0em; border-left: 12px solid transparent;
      border-right: 12px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 12px solid #CCCC9A;
      margin-top: -0.75em;
      position: relative;
     }
```

CSS Code for Dropdown box

```
    .navbar-custom .dropdown-menu { 
      background-color: #CCCC9A; 
      border-radius: 0.1875em;
      border: 0em;
      padding: 0.75em, 0, 0.875em, 0;
      width: 11.25em;
      margin-top: -0.1875em;
      margin-left: 2.1875em;
      box-shadow: 0em 0.0625em 0.1875em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
     }
```

Comment: it's related to your css rules. also, provide them.

Comment: Samvel, see CSS rules for the particular setup below.

**CSS for gold triangle**
.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu .gold-triangle {
    width: 0em;
    height: 0em;
    border-left: 12px solid transparent;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid #CCCC9A;
    margin-top: -0.75em;
    position: relative;
  }

Comment: **CSS Rules for dropdown box**
.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #CCCC9A;
    border-radius: 0.1875em;
    border: 0em;
    padding: 0.75em, 0, 0.875em, 0;
    width: 11.25em;
    margin-top: -0.1875em;
    margin-left: 2.1875em;
    box-shadow: 0em 0.0625em 0.1875em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }

Comment: update your question with adding the rules you provided. but the thing you want is pseudo selectors: `::after, ::before`

Comment: Samvel I added the CSS code. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I understand what you mean now with using the ::Before and ::After.  Thanks. I will updated once I have the solution.

Comment: Everything is working now @SamvelAleqsanyan